# Make div grow up left instead of down right

Tags: html, css

The div should grow up left, however, it does the opposite as of now.

The margin-left and top is necessary by the way.

Quick gif showcasing the issue: https://gyazo.com/ce51c504698395c26cffefb9b74e7e3e

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#img-wrapper {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="img-wrapper">
   <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12225358/Pug-On-White-01.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "should grow up left"?

Comment: @sebastian nielsen do you mean that when the width is increased then it should grow towards the left??

Comment: Yes, it should grow up and to the left. As of now, it grows downward and to the right. See the gif.

Comment: Try Making Div's Position as  Absolute and making right as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
#a {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
#img-wrapper {
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, it doesn't work. Take a look at this gif: https://gyazo.com/184ef711bad9b85c9d983ffc6d10a69d

Comment: Well, "position: absolute;" is not allowed. As that will cause other problems on my website. That's why I wrote "margin-left and margin-top is necessary".

Comment: as long as we added 'position: relative;' to #a, it will not harm.

Comment: Without Position you can't do that.

Comment: Well, I gave your code a try. It grows up, which is good, however, it stills grows to the right. Take a look: https://gyazo.com/6b94f89dedc4c673a9ba30884289c059

Comment: Hey, my bad, I changed the width of the img not "img-wrapper". It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image going from right to left by increasing `width` property, you should give it float property:

```
#img-wrapper {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0; // if you want it to start from top right edge
}
```

Answer (score 0):

added `margin-right: 10%;` `float: right;`

```
#img-wrapper {
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

#img-wrapper {
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    width: 52%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12225358/Pug-On-White-01.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it still doesn't grow up and to the right. Take a look: https://gyazo.com/f0620a07f1be222de4a6a9a248197cad

Comment: @sebastian nielsen check now. i have updated my answer. thanks

Comment: Well, it grows upwards now, which is good! However, it stills grows to the right, I want it to grow to the left instead.

Comment: @sebastian nielsen  in the gif you are increasing the width of `img` and in the question you are increasing of `#img-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem isn't about getting the image to "grow up left" but is about positioning the `#img-wrapper`.

You can solve this by positioning the `#img-wrapper` absolutely and specifying its `bottom` and `right` position. I've added a :hover style so you can see it 'grow' on hover.

A word of warning though. Positioning something of unknown/variable size using percentages is going to give you very mixed results at different viewport sizes. Perhaps what you want isn't quite as described but I think you should be looking at a more flexible solution such as using flexbox.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:relative;
}

#img-wrapper {
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#img-wrapper:hover {
  width: 70%;
}


img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="img-wrapper">
   <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12225358/Pug-On-White-01.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

#img-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20% 0 0 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Its better if you provide some explaination

Comment: you can replace this code with your code too, i have added relative in #a and after that #img-wrapper id  absolute and top left transform and margin as well